# How to stretch a text field relative to data width in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, field, stretch

I have a text field followed by a static text field and I am trying to do 2 things with it:

1. Get the text field to stretch horizontally (not wrap) when text is longer then the field width and
2. Push the static text field right when the text field to the left of it stretches

Both of the fields are contained within a frame.

I have both fields set to positionType=float and the text field set to stretchWithOverflow=true, which enable text to wrap vertically but not stretch horizontally.

Is it possible to achieve 1 and 2 above? If so How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of having 2 text fields (dynamic and static), you can have 1 text field with value as `$F{Field} + "statix text"`. This will probably fix your issue. Also, you can set the "width" and "stretch with overflow" properties, as per your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Well it's bad news!! According to Jaspersoft's documentation on [stretching fields](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/index.html) it is not possible to stretch the width of a field:

> "Usually, the stretching process refers to the height adjustment only.
>   When stretching report elements, adjusting the width could affect also
>   the page width and raise unexpected errors at runtime (for instance,
>   truncated information could be printed out on pages). This is why
>   stretching an element let its width unchanged, while its height gets
>   definitely enlarged in order to make room for all information that
>   have to be displayed." *(Jaspersoft documentation [v4.5.0], 2011)*

However a solution to the original issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979543/non-fixed-width-text-in-a-static-string-jasper-reports/8979785#8979785) thanks to @mdahlman

Answer (score 0):

Just select text field and from its textfield properties choose "stretch with overflow" and it will change its height dynamically according to text .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzvvM.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).