# Non-fixed width text in a static string - Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, width, field

So as I have learned since this post: [How to stretch a text field relative to data width in Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979134/how-to-stretch-field-horizontally-in-jasper-reports) it is not possible to stretch the width of text fields. So I am trying to establish now whether it is possible to embed static text within a text field?

I need to achieve a scenario something like this:

> "You're current employer [non-fixed width text] will contact you
>   soon."

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in Jasper? I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a single Text Field with a value like this:

```
"Your current employer, " + $F{Employer} + ", will contact you soon."
```

Or alternatively, something like this:

```
msg("Your current employer, {0}, will contact you soon.", $F{Employer})
```

There are other possibilities... but those are the most common. In short, it's common.