# How to adjust text field with stretch with overflow

Tags: jasper-reports

I use iReport 4.5.1 (I know it's so so old but it's at work and I don't have authority to upgrade it). 
Anyway, I have a text field with following value:

```
$F{field1} + " — " + $F{field2}
```

Both field1 and field 2 are of `java.lang.String` type.
Since neither field1 nor field2 has consistent length, I have checked the stretch with the overflow property as TRUE. But the problem is that when I have a long text for field2 the rest of it comes below field1 while I need it begin right below field2.

Actually, it appears like:

```
something for field1 — something very long 
for field2
```

While I need it like:

```
something for field1 — something very long 
                       for field2
```

and if I put `$F{field1}` in a separate text field, since it doesn't have a fixed length, sometimes an extra space appears after `$F{field1}` or if I set its stretch with overflow property as TRUE, `$F{field1}` appears in two lines, which I don't like it either.
Generally, I need `$F{field1}` appear in one line with only one space after that and `$F{field2}` to split in two lines, if its length is too long, and appear as I described above.

Is there any way to do that?

Here's jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="adjust_textField" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT code, name FROM test_co1 WHERE id = $P{parameter1}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="41" y="66" width="270" height="20"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Gill Sans MT" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{code} + " — " + $F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Which reads data from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_co1 (
  id INTEGER,
  code TEXT,
  name TEXT
) ;

/* Data for the 'public.test_co1' table  (Records 1 - 54) */

INSERT INTO public.test_co1 ("id", "code", "name")
VALUES 
  (1, E'J', E'WELDING & CUTTING'),
  (2, E'L', E'CONFINED SPACES'),
  (6, E'N', E'COMPRESSED GAS/FUEL CYLINDERS'),
  (15, E'W18', E'java code to iReportWEAPON SAFETY FOR PROP. MASTERS'),
  (45, E'GD$', E'java code to iReportGENERAL SAFETY TRAINING/INJURY & ILLNESS PREVENTION PROGRAM'),
  (49, E'GD$', E'java code to iReportENVIRONMENTAL SAFETY');
```

When you enter 45 as the parameter value, it displays it as

```
GD$ — java code to iReportGENERAL SAFETY
TRAINING/INJURY & ILLNESS PREVENTION
PROGRAM
```

while I need it as :

```
GD$ — java code to iReportGENERAL SAFETY
      TRAINING/INJURY & ILLNESS PREVENTION
      PROGRAM
```

Comment: this link describes my question in some way, but I have the static text in the middle so the answer to that doesn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979134/how-to-stretch-a-text-field-relative-to-data-width-in-jasper-reports

Comment: Must this use a single field? Three columns, instead, would simplify the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is that if I use three columns I still have the problem of adjusting the first field in one line

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="adjust_textField" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f5fbc25f-d746-4a3c-bb20-80389233ba42">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, code, name FROM test_co1
WHERE id = $P{parameter1}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="b40f6b54-cdd8-4bed-8a3f-96808e8eeecb"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code} + " — "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="180" height="30" uuid="db6850d8-c213-4544-8bae-cf515ae7484e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I haven't tested it, but the idea is to create two fields that will stretch in height with each other. The first field is right-aligned and the second field is left-aligned.

This was written using JasperReports 6.3, so the code might not work in an older version. The approach, though, is likely correct.

Comment: Nice solution! it works if I don't need to keep the whole text left aligned