# How to styling a static text partially according to a global style in a Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

## Question

I have a simple text field like this:

```xml
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="10" />
    <text>Hello world!</text>
</staticText>
```

Also in my document I have a style like this:

```xml
<style name="highlight" forecolor="#FF3333" />
```

How can I apply the style `highlight` to just the word "world" in my text field?

## What I have tried so far

I checked whether I can just use multiple text fields (in this case three, one for "Hello ", one for "world" and one for "!"). In this case I could just use `<reportElement ... style="highlight" />` on the element for "world". But it looks like there is [no way to align the three text field vertically automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979134/how-to-stretch-a-text-field-relative-to-data-width-in-jasper-reports). Since in my case the text is static I could of course align the text fields manually, however this is quite cumbersome to do and as soon as someone wants to change the font or the font size or exchange just a single letter in the text I need to realign everything.

Another option is to use styled text. This actually works:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="10" />
    <textElement markup="styled" />
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[
        "Hello <style forecolor='#FF3333'>world</style>!"
    ]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This works fine by itself, but I cannot refer to my `highlight`-style - I have to repeat the color here which is not maintenance friendly either.

Comment: `How can I apply the style highlight to just the word "world" in my text field?` - You was right using markup in this case. You can also try to use several staticText elements (one for showing "Hello" word and another one for "world!" part). Another way - you can try create and use parameter for storing forecolor in case using `markup="styled" `. This is alternate of having style - you can change color just at one place